# What is Tokyo Ghoul RA?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I saw on "Tokyo Ghoul RA" episode 5 on Pinterest, and it is something totally different from Tokyo Ghoul regular episode 5. Could someone please explain what the difference is?

Comment: could you add a link to the pinterest post?

Answer (score 3):

RA is another synonym for "Tokyo Ghoul: Root A", which is the second season.

It has 12 episodes.